# How to enlarge swap space on a linux VPS in order to compile an R package?

Tags: linux, debian, compile, r

Matt Lacey explained [how to compile dplyr on low memory VPS](http://lacey.se/posts/compiling-dplyr-on-low-memory-vps/). He managed to install dplyr by adding a larger swap space. Unfortunately this operation is not permitted on my VPS (Virtual Private Server): "swapon failed: Operation not permitted". Here is the output:

```
$ sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile    
$ sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
$ sudo mkswap /swapfile
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 1048572 KiB
no label, UUID=3bfbcf12-6b81-46b4-96b0-7de37fa1640b
$  sudo swapon /swapfile
swapon: /swapfile: swapon failed: Operation not permitted
$ cat /proc/swaps
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/null                               partition       131072  3060    -1
```

EDIT 
I used [other instructions from digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-virtual-memory-swap-file-on-a-vps) to create a swap file. But they failed too:

```
sudo swapon /var/swap.img 
swapon: /var/swap.img: swapon failed: Operation not permitted
```

There is [a related issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/262) in the dplyr package's repository.

Are there other, recommended ways to enlarge the swap space?

Comment: Are you on an OpenVZ machine? If so, then you may take a look at this purported trick, http://www.serveridol.com/2014/08/03/how-do-i-create-swap-partition-in-linux-mkswap-operation-not-permitted/, which is widely discussed on the Net. I never tried it myself, so I will not try to sell it as **the** solution, but given the dire straits you seem to find yourself in, it might be worth a try.

Comment: Look interesting. Might get you in trouble if you abuse it, but this might be an option if you needed it just once and right now. (As opposed to waiting to the VPS provider).  @Paul4forest. If this works then please leave some feedback.

Comment: Yes, pls, leave a feedback if this works. But then, on a different note: do you really want to run the R statistics package on such a small server??? It will easily hog out all of your resources.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae the link you posted proposes 2 solutions: (1) create a swap file or (2)create a swap partition. I used [instruction from digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-virtual-memory-swap-file-on-a-vps) to create a swap file. But this is not permitted `swapon: /var/swap.img: swapon failed: Operation not permitted`.  I didn't figure out how to do option (2), since `ls /dev` doesn't show me any sda.

Comment: This small server is good enough to process a gigabyte of data and share the result in the form of static files.

Comment: The link I posted has a solution starting with `Create a script file named “create_swap.sh” `. That's what you should try to do. It is quite different from what you have tried so far.

Comment: Executing the script file fails with the message: `#sh create_swap.sh 
create_swap.sh: 2: create_swap.sh: Bad substitution`.

Comment: Running the script with bash instead of sh doesn't return an error. `sudo bash create_swap.sh 4096`. But it doesn't add any swap space. I still have `mem total 1024`  and `swap total  128`. @MariusMatutiae To answer your first question I am on openVZ.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can either:

- Add a parttion to page to,
- or add a file (as you tried) to page to,
- or add more physical memory,
- or ask the VPS provider to allocate more resources.

Alternatively, you could compile it on a different host and upload it to the VPS. (e.g. compile, create .rpm or whatever package manager you use on the VPS, upload that rpm).

Comment: Purchasing more physical memory is not an option for this small project. I am using a little test server for 2 € per month. I use it mostly for long running processes and do not want to upgrade. I will try to add a swap partition based on [instructions from the VPS provider](http://help.ovh.co.uk/VPSLinuxPartition).     ***       Thank for suggesting an alternative to compile on a different host. I am using a Debian host and these [Debian packaging instructions for R software](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/) might help.

Comment: An alternative as [mentioned here](http://wiki.vpslink.com/HOWTO:_Install/Configure_Distcc), would be to compile the package on my local machine by using the distributed compiler [distcc](https://github.com/distcc/distcc).

Comment: Latest archived version of the instructions from the VPS provider referred above are here https://web.archive.org/web/20171107001627/http://help.ovh.co.uk:80/VPSLinuxPartition